# Is there any tool by which we can check the compatibility of our web application across various browsers and their versions?

Tags: java, php, asp.net, html, cross-browser

Is there any tool by which we can check the compatibility of our web application across various browsers and their versions ?

Kindly share the same. Thanks.

Comment: Any freeware or open source tool will be excellent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I generally use Chrome, Firefox, Safari and Opera in Mac and then I run a Virtual Box containing Windows XP which runs [IE Tester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage).

IE Tester is used to run IE 5.5 to IE 9 alongside each other in tabs. A great tool.

Answer (score 1):

I've found [browsershots](http://browsershots.org/) to be very useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Microsoft Expression, there is a SuperPreview that displays it in different browsers

The best thing to do is to validate your website (Visual Studio does that for you, or go to one of the online validators)